# What's the minimum permission so users can tick on GitHub Task lists?

Tags: github, permissions

GitHub introduced some time ago [Task lists](https://help.github.com/articles/writing-on-github/#task-lists).

What are the minimum permission I need to set-up so collaborators/assignees are able to tick those boxes on the issue of the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give write access to your repository, as checking off a task list item in an existing comment is an edit action.

This is the explanation which I've received from GH support:

> We have discussed the possibility of offering a more refined permission scheme. There, people will be able to edit issues, but not push to that repository. I am afraid I don't have anything concrete I can promise currently though. Our team will consider it.

See also: [GH #590 - Give permission to project members to check off a task list items, without ability to push (unofficial issue tracking repo)](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/590)

Answer (score 1):

On the [wiki](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/), it may be that collaborators are by default able to check of the boxes on issues/pull requests, since they can edit them.